# Problems when launching the telegram echo bot on Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Installed aiogram version 20.0.4. Python - version 3.10.4. Wrote the echo of the bot for telegrams, when the bot is allowed to /start, it is silent. Where is the mistake ?

```
`import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = '...'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hi!\nI'm EchoBot!\nPowered by 
aiogram.")

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)`
```

Comment: Please share the error in the log file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Quickly change your Bot Token and don't share it on SO.